# Java GUI popup window netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I am making a GUI in netbeans. I have a button and when users clicks it i want to popup a jframe. How is this possible? could someone give me an example?

Comment: Don't have a JFrame "pop-up" another JFrame. The second window should be a JDialog. The best way to learn how to do this is to go to the Swing tutorials and read up all you can as well as by making the Java API your best buddy. Then write lots and lots of code.

Comment: For an example of creating and showing a JDialog, please see my code in [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8524302/522444) or for a variation, please check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7017147/522444).

Comment: @Michael Tanasa use JDialog / JWindow

Comment: Thanks guys, used JDialog and it worked out great.

Answer (score 1):

Are you programming a NetBeans RCP application? 
If so then take a look to the Dialogs API: http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-dialogs/index.html?org/openide/NotifyDescriptor.html
If not, give a try NetBeans RCP can improve the code quality and modularity of your java desktop applications.